# How can I use Dagger 2 with custom view?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I read documentation and found, that I can inject Activity objects with 
"HasActivityInjector" and Fragment objects with "HasFragmentInjector", but how can inject View objects? Like I have custom view instead fragment, how can inject in it?

Comment: let me clarify, you want to inject some object inside of your custom view?

Comment: exactly this, my friend

Comment: I have added and eddited answer bellow, let me know if you have troubles, I just realised that I gave you examples written in kotlin.

Comment: thank you, but I guess, you wrote answer in old way, but how inject view with: "AndroidInjection.inject(this);" , @ContributesAndroidInjector, AndroidInjector.Builder<> ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can share only one that I have wrote, I don't know what are you asking. I use 2.8 dagger version, maybe it's a bit old, but still works (That was enterprise and I don't want to upgrade anything without needs after release). There are a lot of views injected this way.

Comment: @A.Shevchuk got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `inject` method inside of your component like

```
fun inject(view: YourCustomView)
```

and then, when you are using your view on some activity or fragment, call

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        yourCustomView.inject(component)
}
```

`component` could be obtained inside fragment's\activity's `onCreate` from your injection.

On your view you need to implement `inject` method like this:

```
fun inject(component: Component) {
        component.inject(this)
    }
```

That's all, now you can inject everything from your component inside of your custom view.

Comment: You can't get component of Activity now with dagger2.12, how would this solution work now?